# How can I get the count of rows in my uploaded excel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, xlsx

I have uploaded an excel and need to read it and get the count of the number of rows in it.

I have tried the below codes but it doesn't seen to work out.

I have been getting so many errors like,"_fs.readFileSync is not a function" "f.slice is not a function" and currently I am stuck at "input.replace is not a function". Please let me know where am I going wrong or what actually needs to be done

Component.ts

```
<pre>

    proceedUpload(){

         if(this.file != null) {


        var workbook = XLSX.read(this.file);


        var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];


        var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
        var number = excelRows.length();

          if( number > 0 )
          {
              this.uploadMessage = true;
          }
          else
          {
            this.uploadMessage = false;
          }


        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Files', this.file);

        this.http.post("Url", formData).map(res => res.json())
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
          .subscribe(
            data => console.log('success'),
            error => console.log(error)
          )

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please upload a file!")
        } 
    </pre>
```

Component.html

```
<div *ngIf="uploadMessage">
<p>{{number}} uploaded!!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try   var number = excelRows.length;

Comment: Yes I did, doesn't help :(

Answer (score 3):

```
const table = XLSX.readFile('mytable.xlsx');
const sheet = table.Sheets[table.SheetNames[0]];
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
console.log(range.e.r);
```

[Source](https://techoverflow.net/2018/05/28/how-to-iterate-over-xlsx-rows-using-js-xlsx/)

Comment: I get the same error.."input.replace is not a function".

Answer (score 1):

```
let excelRowsObjArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
```

On this one you can do:

```
excelRowsObjArr.length
```

For more info you can go here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Parse-Excel-File-XLS-and-XLSX-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: On using sheet_to_row_object_array I get the error that "Property 'sheet_to_row_object_array' does not exist on type 'XLSX$Utils'"